# How to stop/terminate a python script from running?

Tags: python, execution, terminate, termination

I wrote a program in IDLE to tokenize text files and it starts to tokeniza 349 text files! How can I stop it? How can I stop a running Python program?

Comment: `ctrl+c` should kill it. Alternatively, `kill -9` it

Comment: Many answers here are platform-specific. Search for your platform (Windows, Linux, Mac, something else?)

Comment: So many friends spent effort to write answers, but none got accepted, yet :-(

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To stop your program, just press <kbd>Control</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: This method worked on my windows laptop, but on my linux desktop, it showed `^C` in the terminal and the system monitor showed python is still using a lot of CPU...

Comment: Is it possible to resume the script after stopping it?

Comment: @Gathide If you want to pause the process and put it in the background, press `Ctrl + Z` (at least on Linux). Then, if you want to kill it, run `kill %n` where "n" is the number you got next to "Stopped" when you pressed `Ctrl + Z`. If you want to resume it, run `fg`.

Comment: Does not work if you have a general except: clause in the program.  The except: catches the interrupt, does something (or not), and then the program merrily continues.

Comment: @DragonLord Your general except should have an special except for the error trown by Ctrl+C. Anyway, general excepts are usually discouraged.

Answer (score 210):

You can also do it if you use the `exit()` function in your code. More ideally, you can do `sys.exit()`. `sys.exit()` which **might** terminate Python even if you are running things in parallel through the `multiprocessing` package.

Note: In order to use the `sys.exit()`, you must import it: `import sys`

Comment: Note: I could find examples in which `sys.exit(1)` doesn't stop the process. I basically have multiple threads and each of them blocks on external processes started by `Popen`. I need a nuclear option to kill all sub-processes created by the Python process as well as the Python process itself. Didn't find so far.

Comment: sys.exit() doesn't kill the process but raise SystemExit Exception which doesn't stop execution by closing the programm

Answer (score 69):

If your program is running at an interactive console, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception on the main thread.

If your Python program doesn't catch it, the `KeyboardInterrupt` will cause Python to exit. However, an `except KeyboardInterrupt:` block, or something like a bare `except:`, will prevent this mechanism from actually stopping the script from running.

Sometimes if `KeyboardInterrupt` is not working you can send a `SIGBREAK` signal instead; on Windows, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> may be handled by the interpreter without generating a catchable `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

However, these mechanisms mainly only work if the Python interpreter is running and responding to operating system events. If the Python interpreter is not responding for some reason, the most effective way is to terminate the entire operating system process that is running the interpreter. The mechanism for this varies by operating system.

In a Unix-style shell environment, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to *suspend* whatever process is currently controlling the console. Once you get the shell prompt back, you can use `jobs` to list suspended jobs, and you can kill the first suspended job with `kill %1`. (If you want to start it running again, you can continue the job in the foreground by using `fg %1`; read your shell's manual on job control for more information.)

Alternatively, in a Unix or Unix-like environment, you can find the Python process's PID (process identifier) and kill it by PID. Use something like `ps aux | grep python` to find which Python processes are running, and then use `kill <pid>` to send a `SIGTERM` signal.

The `kill` command on Unix sends `SIGTERM` by default, and a Python program can install a signal handler for `SIGTERM` using the `signal` module. In theory, any signal handler for `SIGTERM` should shut down the process gracefully. But sometimes if the process is stuck (for example, blocked in an uninterruptable IO sleep state), a `SIGTERM` signal has no effect because the process can't even wake up to handle it.

To forcibly kill a process that isn't responding to signals, you need to send the `SIGKILL` signal, sometimes referred to as `kill -9` because `9` is the numeric value of the `SIGKILL` constant. From the command line, you can use `kill -KILL <pid>` (or `kill -9 <pid>` for short) to send a `SIGKILL` and stop the process running immediately.

On Windows, you don't have the Unix system of process signals, but you can forcibly terminate a running process by using the `TerminateProcess` function. Interactively, the easiest way to do this is to open Task Manager, find the `python.exe` process that corresponds to your program, and click the "End Process" button. You can also use the `taskkill` command for similar purposes.

Answer (score 62):

- To stop a python script just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
- Inside a script with `exit()`, you can do it.
- You can do it in an interactive script with just exit.
- You can use `pkill -f name-of-the-python-script`.

Comment: The last option is especially useful when you run the script in a detached mode, e.g. ```python script.py&```

Comment: @AEM WOW! what a good answer!
I searched for a way to kill the python program outside the script and your answer was exactly the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 61):

To stop a python script using the keyboard: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

To stop it using code (This has worked for me on Python 3) :

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```

you can also use:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

or:

```
exit()
```

or:

```
raise SystemExit
```

Comment: Thanks. SystemExit is the way to go.

Comment: only os._exit(0) worked for me but for some reason all the others didnt, glad i found os one out, Thank you!

Comment: `raise SystemExit` is especially useful if you have never-ending threads (using the multithreading package). The process won't stop if you terminate it using any other method, unless you do ctrl+c twice - but I need an automated restarter :)

Comment: For me also os._exit(0) only worked. Thanks

Answer (score 50):

To stop a running program, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the process.

To handle it programmatically in python, import the `sys` module and use `sys.exit()` where you want to terminate the program.

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Comment: This won't work if called from a subprocess.

Answer (score 37):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> it is more powerful than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Like Daniel Pryden clarifies in his answer, the Break key on the keyboard could also be labelled Pause, for those who were confused like me. :)

Answer (score 15):

When I have a python script running on a linux terminal, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+`\` works. (not <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>)

Comment: This is far better than `Ctrl` + `Z` as that only suspends the process

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> should do it, if you're caught in the python shell. Keep in mind that instances of the script could continue running in background, so under linux you have to kill the corresponding process.

Comment: this is useful when running (many) parallel processes and CTRL-C just won't kill them all. After CTRL-Z, you may check `jobs` or `ps` to then `kill 8923754` or whatever jobid/process id you need to kill

Answer (score 9):

exit() will kill the Kernel if you're in Jupyter Notebook so it's not a good idea. `raise` command will stop the program.

Answer (score 7):

To stop your program, just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

or `exit()`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with Spyder, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>  and you will restart the kernel, also you will stop the program.

Comment: FINALLY.  A solution that works in Spyder on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

you can also use the `Activity Monitor` to stop the py process

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works for me on Windows 10. Also, putting `exit()` at the end also works.

Answer (score 4):

Windows solution: <kbd>Control</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Macbook solution: <kbd>Control (^)</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Another way is to open a terminal, type `top`, write down the `PID` of the process that you would like to kill and then type on the terminal: `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

or

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: What exactly these shortcuts do??

Comment: @rhoitjadhav, sometimes in windows a python application doesn't stop by pressing "ctrl+c" only, and a lot of keyboards don't have an explicit "break" key either. So, these shortcuts help you to stop your python application in the terminal if and when required.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and Task Manager will pop up. Find the Python command running, right click on it and and click Stop or Kill.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little too late to respond but if you're finding it hard to use `sys.exit()` or `exit()` and want to kill the python script from within, this might be helpful

```
import os
import sys
os.system(F"pkill -f {sys.argv[0]}")
```

Sometimes, in a really long script with many simultaneous threads, it is difficult to kill just with `sys.exit` but this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a script to process 349 files, but want to test with fewer, just write a nonexisting word like 'stop' in your list, which will cause a stop in the form of an exception. This avoids dialogs like do you want to kill your process if you use `exit()` or `quit()`