# terminating python2 script & service with CTRL+Z

Tags: python, python-2.7, process

Currently whenever I press `CTRL + Z` on a lengthy script I was given, it immediately terminates the script (`[1+]` stopped(`SIGTSTP`)  `./test.py`) which is what I want, but it also leaves the `python2` process running (when I type ps to look at processes), which forces me to use `killall -9 python2`, which I do not want to do every time. Is there a way to immediately terminate a script that doesn't leave the python2 process running in the background?

There is no `SIGTSTP` currently in the code that I see but I did try using the following code with no luck. It didn't even exit the script when I pressed `CTRL + Z`.

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    sys.exit("CTRL+Z pressed. Exiting Test")

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGSTP is a signal to *suspend* a process, it sounds like you want to terminate a process. You can try sending Ctrl-C or CTRL-D instead, which should send a SIGINT signal.

I believe you could also try CTRL-\ which sends SIGQUIT.

Comment: CTRL + D did nothing during the script. CTRL + C displayed ^C on my screen but the script continued running. CTRL + \ seems to have done the trick though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl + C`. `SIGTSTP` suspends the process, hence why it keeps it open, but does not terminate it.
(Note: On a Linux terminal use `Ctrl + \`, otherwise use `Ctrl + C` or `Ctrl + D`)

Or just use `sys.exit()`

Comment: Also check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running