# Python script stops running by pressing a button

Tags: python-3.x, button, events

I want to interrupt or stop running a python script by pressing a button from outside like in assembler or C. Is there any possibility to implement this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop/terminate a python script from running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running) Please note that [asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Unfortuanetly not. Is there a way to change the Ctrl + C Keyboard Interrupt or define it's own?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.

You can press control C, for both Mac and windows to interrupt a program execution.

Thank You.

Comment: yes i know, but is it not possible to define it's own interrupt event, like pressing an external button?