# In Python code below, how can I immediately exit the code?

Tags: python

I have been trying below this two days, but cannot make it work.

I have tried

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
sys.exit()
exit()
control+C
```

, and so on.

I have tried the code, but it terminates only after 30 seconds or 1 minute. It seems like "listener" in the code makes the code complicated.

**I need to make the code terminate immediately when I press ESC.** "Terminate" here means stop the code from running or close the entire terminal. Either way is fine, but it needs to work "immediately".

I am using Windows10. It does not need to be compatible with MAC os.

```
import pydirectinput
import datetime
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
TOGGLE_KEY = KeyCode(char="`")
clicking = False
mouse = Controller()

def clicker():    
    global fishpause
    global a_press
    global d_press
    global maxtime
    duration = 0
    while True and duration <= maxtime:
        qtime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        if qtime.hour == 11 and qtime.minute == 30: 
            print("Quiting by using an error...")
            pydirectinput.keydown('alt')                
        else:
            if clicking:
                mouse.press(Button.right)
                #print("Button pressed")
                goleft(fishpause, a_press)
                duration += 1
                print(f"Duration is: {duration}")
                time.sleep(0.5)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.release(Button.right)
    
def toggle_event(key):
    if key == TOGGLE_KEY:
        global clicking
        clicking = not clicking
        print("Clicking changed")

def goleft(fishpause, a_press):
    pydirectinput.press('a', presses=1, interval=a_press)
    print("Moving left")
    pydirectinput.PAUSE = fishpause
    print(f"PAUSING: {fishpause}")
  
maxtime = 4500
fishpause = 9.0 
a_press = 0.1 
time.sleep(1)
print("Starting")
pydirectinput.press('esc', presses=1, interval=0.1)
click_thread = threading.Thread(target=clicker)
click_thread.start()
time.sleep(3)
with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I think you'd find your answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running), But if I was to do something about this then I suggest you try os._exit and process kill (pkill -f name-of-the-python-script)

Comment: Yes I also tried kill -9 but it stops really slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program won't exit while the click_thread is still running.
If the clicker knows that it's supposed to exit it can break the loop and return.  Alternatively, if you mark the thread as a daemon:

```
click_thread = threading.Thread(target=clicker, daemon=True)
```

then it will exit when the main program exits.

You can test this with the tiny program below.  Try with daemon=True and with daemon=None:

```
import threading
import time

def thread_loop():
    while True:
        print("!");
        time.sleep(.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bkgnd = threading.Thread(target=thread_loop, daemon=True)
    bkgnd.start()
    print("exit main")
```

Comment: Current docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects