# Stop python script running in virtual enviroment on remote machine

Tags: python, virtualenv

i have a linux remote server when run a python script in a virtual enviroment. I start this script with

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
python3 ./main.py
```

and it works without problem.
Now, how can I stop this script?
At now, I have to reboot my remote server to stop it.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: You can stop it the same way you would stop any process. Activating the virtual environment only affects the shell. Running `python3` still just starts an ordinary process

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running

Comment: This could be an idea but I hope to find something better. I am looking for process name with ps -e and I have some instances of python3 and I have to be lucky to stop the right one. I have more than one script running in virtual enviroment and more than one process with same name. However thank you for your reply

Comment: @JatinMorar Found a solutition inside that question. With 'pkill -f scriptname' i can stop a script running inside a virtual enviroment. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use kill command or Ctrl + C

```
kill PID
```

or you can as well use:

```
pkill -f main.py
```

Comment: Hello Abdulmajeed, CTRL + C can't help me because my program doesn't run in intercative mode. 
Kill command is quite comfortless because I have to search PID with relative name and I have more than one script in different virtual enviroments and every process have the same name 'python3'
Pkill -f main.py sava me. Thank you a lot!