# Is there a way to immediately stop a python script with a keystroke?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Pretty much the title.

EDIT: I want to be able to stop the script with a keystroke even if I am not in the terminal.

I have a logic for stopping a script with a keystroke but it doesn't stop immediately due to the nature of the while loop

```
import threading
import time
import keyboard


event = threading.Event()

def stop():
    event.set()

keyboard.add_hotkey("esc", stop)

while event.is_set() == 0:
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop/terminate a python script from running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running)
In short, when on Windows, `Ctrl+C` should instantly kill the script from running further.

Comment: @crazydecibel's answer would also work on a MacOS or Linux Machine FYI.

Comment: I didn't specify initially that I want to be able to stop the script even if I am not in the terminal.

Comment: What does "keystroke" mean if you're not in the terminal?

Comment: You could set up a keyboard shortcut in your operating system (assuming linux or mac) to send `killall -9 python3` to a subshell and that will definitely stop it. It will also stop any *other* running Python programs, including potentially those used by your operating system. Not recommended. You will probably have better luck telling us what the Python program is and why you need to be able to stop it when you're not in the terminal.

Comment: Don't use `-9`; that's a last resort for bugging programs.

Comment: @woodford Pressing a key on the keyboard.

Comment: @jaredsmith I am using windows.

Comment: @chepner when you start giving bad advice you go all in :D

Comment: @JaredSmith The program is a video game bot and I want to be able to stop it with a keystroke immediately because if there's no such feature and the only way to stop it is to add a condition to the while loop containing all logic (`while is_pressed('shift') == False:` is what I currently have) it might take quite a bit until the condition is checked again (so the program sees I am pressing a key) and the program stops

Comment: "it might take quite a bit until the condition is checked again" only because your telling the program to sleep? Why? You could just change the program... usually when you get pushback like the kind you're getting here for what you're trying to do it's because [you're trying to solve the wrong problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Think carefully about what you really want to achieve with your bot, and whether your current approach is actually going to achieve your goals.